# shell script does not invoke define variable in autostart script

Tags: usb, mount, script

I try to use the raspberry pi for power point presentation. I want to run this as auto ( I mean once the raspberry pi started or rebooted the power point presentation should run).

Basically it works fine at start or reboot for a fixed usb. Issue is, once I change the USB, mounting point is changed for the replacement of the USB. So, I wrote a generic script to accommodate.

Here is my script:

```
1. File Name:drvusb.sh 

#!/bin/bash
drv=`mount|grep media|awk '{print $3}'`
usbfolder="$drv/temple2.ppt"
/usr/bin/soffice --show $usbfolder --norestore

2. under /home/pi/.config/autostart
File Name:  powerppt.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=PowerPoint PPT
Exec=/home/pi/drvusb.sh
StartupNotify=false
```

When I power-up or rebooted I got the following error message.My variable (/media/pi/2E02-6FE6) is missing here.

[image]

**see below my test:**

[image]

I appreciate if any help on this issue.

Note: When I ran ./drvusb.sh under /home/pi powerpoint view works well no error.
So, only issue from autostart

Comment: I tried to edit you code to use proper code formatting. I don't know what you have done, it resisted all attempts at normal formatting. I suggest you replace with plain text so it can be easily read.

Comment: @Millways, Done

Comment: This question is not specific to the Pi. The likely problem is that `drv` is not found. You have NO CHECKS on the output of your command, which should be standard practice! PS Using lower case for shell variables makes scripts difficult to read, and is not usual as it risks collision with commands.

Comment: Your mount will list ALL media, even unmounted media, as the mount points are persistent. I NEVER use automount, because of its unreliability.

Comment: @Millways, Thanks for your suggestion and now I started use uppercase for the shell variables. However, the result still same. This particular application we will not  put any other devices on other USB ports.I am not a regular linux or unix guy. Someone asked me cheapest way put powerpoint presentation for their temple and I suggested Raspberry Pi . This is my first project.
Anyway, I overcome the issue by following method by script:
unmounted auto mounted USB device
mount the usb device
invoke the powerpoint. worked successfully for any USB pen-drive.

Comment: "Anyway, I overcome the issue by following method" - you could post that as an answer (perhaps detailing your approach a bit), so that people see right away this is solved.